# pandas.date_range accurate freq parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to generate a `pandas.DateTimeIndex` with a samplefrequency of 5120 Hz. That gives a period of `increment=0.0001953125` seconds.

If you try to use `pandas.date_range()`, you need to specify the frequency (parameter `freq`) as `str` or as `pandas.DateOffset`. The first one can only handle an accuracy up to 1 ns, the latter has a terrible performance compared to the `str` and has even a worse error.

When using the string, I construct is as follows:

```
freq=str(int(increment*1e9))+'N')
```

which performs my 270 Mb file in less than 2 seconds, but I have an error (in the DateTimeIndex) after 3 million records of about 1500 µs.

When using the `pandas.DateOffset`, like this

```
freq=pd.DateOffset(seconds=increment)
```

it parses the file in 1 minute and 14 seconds, but has an error of about a second.

I also tried constructing the `DateTimeIndex` using

```
starttime + pd.to_timedelta(cumulativeTimes, unit='s')
```

This sum takes also ages to complete, but is the only one which doesn't have the error in the resulting `DateTimeIndex`.

How can I achieve a performant generation of the `DateTimeIndex`, keeping my accuracy?

Comment: If there seems to be a bug in pandas, can you open an issue about it at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues?

Comment: @joris I thought there were a bug in pandas, but I don't think so anymore. It's just that pandas has an accuracy of 1 ns and everything else is due to rounding errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a pure numpy implementation to fix this:

```
accuracy = 'ns'

relativeTime = np.linspace(
        offset,
        offset + (periods - 1) * increment,
        periods)

def unit_correction(u):
    if u is 's':
        return 1e0
    elif u is 'ms':
        return 1e3
    elif u is 'us':
        return 1e6
    elif u is 'ns':
        return 1e9

# Because numpy only knows ints as its date datatype, 
# convert to accuracy.
return (np.datetime64(starttime) 
        + (relativeTime*unit_correction(accuracy)).astype(
            "timedelta64["+accuracy+"]"
            )
        )
```

(this is the github pull request for people interested: https://github.com/adamreeve/npTDMS/pull/31)

Answer (score 0):

I think I reach a similar result with the function below (although it uses only nanosecond precision):

```
def date_range_fs(duration, fs, start=0):
    """ Create a DatetimeIndex based on sampling frequency and duration
    Args:
        duration: number of seconds contained in the DatetimeIndex
        fs: sampling frequency
        start: Timestamp at which de DatetimeIndex starts (defaults to POSIX
               epoch)
    Returns: the corresponding DatetimeIndex
    """
    return pd.to_datetime(
        np.linspace(0, 1e9*duration, num=fs*duration, endpoint=False),
        unit='ns',
        origin=start)
```