# High (and not round) frequency DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, signal-processing

Although pandas is wonderful to process low frequency signals (e.g. on the order of the day/second) I find it always more difficult to manages signals with high frequency or/and with non-round frequencies.

Imagine one wants to create a `DatetimeIndex` for a frequency of 300Hz and a duration of 1 second. The problem is that a frequency of 300 Hz lead to a step of 0.00333333333 with an infinite number decimals. A solution could be to use the `date_range` function with the highest possible resolution (nano-second):

```
pd.date_range(start=0, periods=300, freq='3333333ns') # start on UNIX epoch because I do not care
```

The result of this is:

```
DatetimeIndex([          '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.003333333',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.006666666',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.009999999',
               ...
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.989999901',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.993333234',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.996666567'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=300, freq='3333333N')
```

As you can see the last sample is already getting delayed compared to the expected result:

```
1 - 0.003333333 = 0.9966666666
```

The solution I found to this problem is:

```
def date_range_fs(duration, fs, start=0):
    """ Create a DatetimeIndex based on sampling frequency and duration
    Args:
        duration: number of seconds contained in the DatetimeIndex
        fs: sampling frequency
        start: Timestamp at which de DatetimeIndex starts (defaults to POSIX
               epoch)
    Returns: the corresponding DatetimeIndex
    """
    return pd.to_datetime(
        np.linspace(0, 1e9*duration, num=fs*duration, endpoint=False),
        unit='ns',
        origin=start)
```

with expected result:

```
> date_range_fs(1, 300)
DatetimeIndex([          '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.003333333',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.006666666',
                  '1970-01-01 00:00:00.010000',
               ...
                  '1970-01-01 00:00:00.990000',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.993333333',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.996666666'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=300, freq=None)
```

But this solution is not ideal because it returns a `DatetimeIndex` without a frequency (`freq=None`) and it is thus not possible to leverage all pandas functionalities such as the conversion to `PeriodIndex`.

**My question is the following: is their anyway to obtain the same result but with a fully defined `DatetimeIndex` (i..e. freq is not None) ?**

I was thinking about developing my own `DateOffset` but that seems complicated and I failed to do so. In any case it would be wonderful to have a `Hz` offset alias to be able to write `freq='300Hz'`.

Note a similar problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380654/pandas-date-range-accurate-freq-parameter) but the accepted solution seems complex and not integrated in pandas (and mine is not either).

Comment: Not familiar with *pandas*, but the `freq` value shouldn't have been `'3333333ns'` (7 digits instead of 9) as *3333333ns* =~ *3ms* =~ *1/(300Hz)*?

Comment: 1ns is 10^-9 second so I think it should be OK to use 9 digits to represent a number of nanoseconds. I think it should be OK. What is the rationale for using only 6 digits ?

Comment: I might be getting this wrong, but it is 7 digits. Because 3333333 * 10 ** - 9 = 0,003 (s) => 300 Hz, while 333333333 * 10 ** - 9 = 0.3 (s) => 3 Hz.

Comment: You are completely right, sleeping on it I understood what you meant :) I will correct it in the question. But this does not resolve the problem of infinite decimals / precise frequency.